# Node-Red ui-etable Formatting date tabulator

Tags: json, datetime, dashboard, node-red

i'm tryng to work with the Node-Red ui-etable node that follows http://tabulator.info json format.
I'm unable to display the correct time on the dashboard (that shuold be UTC+2)

`{ "title": "Changed", "field": "stat.changed", "formatter": "datetime", "width": 200, "formatterParams": { "outputFormat": "yyyy.MM.DD HH:mm:ss", "invalidPlaceholder": "(invalid date)", "timezone": "system" } } ]`

[That's what i see on the dashboard but every time should have 2 hours more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBjXN.png)

I've already tried to set "timezone": to other stuff like IANA to see if i could change it but it doesn't seems to work.
Probably defining an offset like: 'UTC+2' should do the trick but i've been unable to do so.